# How to leave this editor?

Tags: escaping, editor

I am on a production server and when I was pulling the latest commit an editor opend showing me this:

[image]

I  managed to open the help screen but its not explained how to exit this editor. Also I cannot find which editor it is, so I cant simply google it.

I tried <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>:q</kbd> but this did not work. In fact after pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> and hitting any button text is added to the file.

Only thing I found out so far is that hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> adds a new line `command`:
[image]
 I tried `:q` , `exit` , `quit` , ' `close` but they are all not known commands. How can I leave this editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT was "joe's" editor. I could leave it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>. See [here](http://www.linuxmaterial.de/tab/joetab.shtml)